# How to make redis instance on AWS to be accessible from outside of VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

Is there any way to temporarily configure my Redis instance on AWS to be accessible publicly from outside of AWS so I can locally connect to it via Redis desktop manager or while debugging application just change the spring's active profile so I can debug locally with live data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is at least one way to do that. Basically, spin a compute instance that you can access from the outside and use an SSH tunnel to forward your local requests to the remote ElastiCache instance.

More information and detailed instructions are available at https://userify.com/blog/howto-connect-redis-ec2-ssh-tunnel-elasticache/